# Add one column to all columns in other dataframe based on share index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add the values of one column in dataframe `df2` to all columns of dataframe `df`. They share a (unique) index, but the order maybe different.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3], "value1":[1,2,3], "value2":[4,5,6]}).set_index("id")
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[3,2], "add":[4,5]}).set_index("id")
```

**expected result:**

```py
result = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3], "value1":[1,2+5,3+4], "value2":[4,5+5,6+4]}).set_index("id")
```

I could merge, and add but I am wondering whether there is a more numpy styled solution. I tried `df+df2` which results in `NaN` everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a numpy styled answer, but here is a pandas style answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3], "value1":[1,2,3], "value2":[4,5,6]}).set_index("id")
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[3,2], "add":[4,5]}).set_index("id")

print(df.update(df + df2))
```

output:

```
    value1  value2
id
1        1       4
2        7      10
3        7      10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try reindex df2 then add:

```
df.add(df2['add'].reindex(df.index, fill_value=0), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
    value1  value2
id                
1        1       4
2        7      10
3        7      10
```

**Note** somehow the following throws an error:

```
df.add(df2['add'], fill_value=0, axis=0)
```

Comment: I was just playing around with that bottom snippet `df.add(df2['add'], fill_value=0, axis=0)` the error seems like a bug to me? pandas version 1.1.5

Comment: @CameronRiddell For me there's a `TODO:` before `NotImplementationError`. So more like a design choice due to lack of bandwidth from the dev's.